# discord.py. FFmpegPCMAudio. Applying filters to running source FFmpeg sub-procces

Tags: ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

How can I apply a new filter (e.g. the same afade) to source, after running voice.play(source) at any time, without killing the current one and creating a new ffmpeg sub-process? For instance the user will call a voice.pause() command, after which the afade=t=out filter will be applied to the current timestamp, and only then will the source audio be stopped.

```
start_time = datetime.now()
audio_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, MUSIC_FOLDER_NAME, audiofile)
audio_long = MP3(audio_path)
end_time = int(audio_long.info.length)
before_options= f'-ss 0:00:00'
options = f'-af "afade=t=in:st=0:d={FADE_DURATION}, afade=t=out:st={end_time-FADE_DURATION}:d={FADE_DURATION}"'
source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=audio_path, executable=FFMPEG_EXECUTABLE_FILE_PATH, before_options=before_options, options=options))
voice.play(source)
```

For now I have this kinda premitive sort of construction (simulating linear afade=t=out effect):

```
volume = 1.0
for _ in range(FADE_DURATION * 10):
    volume -= (1.0 / (FADE_DURATION * 10.0)
    voice.source.volume = volume
    await asyncio.sleep(SLEEP_DURATION)
```